# $T^2 = T + T^*$ implies T is hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

> If any given linear transformation $T$ over a complex inner product vector space satisfies this equation: $T^2 =
>  T + T^*$, prove or disprove that $T$ is hermitian.

I've tried finding disproving example firsts but couldn't find the, So I went on proving the statement.

From $T^2=T+T^*$ I can take the adjoint and thus getting $(T^2)^* = (T+T^*)^* = T+T^* = (T^*)^2$ and therefore getting that ${T^*}^2 = T^2$. But that doesn't yet prove me that $T$ is hermitian. I also tried to show that $\langle Tv,u\rangle = \langle v,Tu\rangle$ for every $u,v$ but didn't work that out either. How can I take it from here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $T^*=T^2-T$. So, $T^*$ commutes with $T$, so $T$ is normal, and
so diagonalizable by a Hermitian matrix. If $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then $\overline\alpha=\alpha^2-\alpha$. Then $\alpha^2=\alpha+\overline\alpha$ is real, and $\alpha=a$ or $ai$ for some real $a$. But in the
latter case $-ia=-a^2-ia$, so $a=0$. So $T$ is normal, with
real eigenvalues, and so is Hermitian.

Comment: Concerning notation: $T^*$ is here conjugate to $A$ or transpose of conjugate of $A$?

Comment: @Widawensen Transpose of complex conjugate.

Comment: I have some problem with notation based on this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix#Examples

Comment: @Widawensen Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: These two articles are not quite coherent :)

Comment: Strangely we have $A^H$ , $A^*$ and even $A^\dagger$ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConjugateTranspose.html, what a mix in notation..

Comment: Furthermore, we can conclude that all the eigenvalues are in $\{0,2\}$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's true because consequently $T^2=2T$.  Additionally if $T$ is invertible $T=2I$.